# Speech Recognizer to convert speech to text during a call in android

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, phone-call, speech-synthesis

I have been looking for a solution which let me convert speech to text during a call. I want to convert voice coming from speaker to text to process that data to generate a viable output and then convert that text to speech which would be send via mic to the person during a call.

All of this work should be done during a call.

Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
public class Speech extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView txtSpeechInput;
private ImageButton btnSpeak;
private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtSpeechInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSpeechInput);
    btnSpeak = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

    // hide the action bar
    getActionBar().hide();

    btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            promptSpeechInput();
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Showing google speech input dialog
 */
private void promptSpeechInput() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

/**
 * Receiving speech input
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                ArrayList<String> result = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
            }
            break;
        }

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    return true;
}
```

}

this xml code..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtSpeechInput"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="26dp"
    android:textStyle="normal" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSpeak"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ico_mic" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/tap_on_mic"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```